# BVH file parsing (calculating transitions)

Tags: graphics, translation

I have a bvh file. I want to calculate translation values of all nodes(bones) in hierarchy w.r.t. global axis or w.r.t. the axis of root node. Except the root node all other values are relative to their parent then how to calculate translation values of all other bones?

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Mathematica user you may find the BVH importer that I wrote as an [answer to a question on Mathematica.stackexchange.com](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63487/57) of some value.